# How can I split the second line when the keyword match two lines by python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a log file like this

> ………………
>   19:07:57.166 [INFO]keyword = 3 ...
>   19:08:13.664 [INFO]keyword = 2 ...
>   ………………
>   19:14:27.062 [INFO]keyword = 3 ...
>   19:14:43.061 [INFO]keyword = 2 ...
>   …………………………

How can  I get only one result like "19:07:57.166" or "19:14:43.061" by keyword "keyword = 2" in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`regular expression` (i.e.: `re` module is powerful to do a such task). Here I give you another way to achieve your goal:

```
# contains the logs data (e.g: it is an example)
lines = [
            "19:07:57.166 [INFO]keyword = 3 ...",
            "19:08:13.664 [INFO]keyword = 2 ...",
            "19:14:27.062 [INFO]keyword = 3 ...",
            "19:14:43.061 [INFO]keyword = 2 ...",
]

results = [] # contains all the results

for line in lines:
    line_split = line.split("[INFO]")
    if line_split[1][10] == '2':
        results.append(line_split[0].strip()) 

print(results)
```

**Outputs:**

```
['19:08:13.664', '19:14:43.061']
```

Answer (score 1):

you can split each line by `'19:07:57.166 [INFO]keyword = 3'.split('[INFO]')`

or you can do it with regex

```py
import re
line = '19:07:57.166 [INFO]keyword = 3'
result = re.match('(.*)\[INFO\](.*)', line)
result.group(1) # 19:07:57.166
result.group(2) # keyword = 3
```

## Update

```py
import re
line = '19:07:57.166 [INFO]keyword = 2'
result = re.match('(.*)\[INFO\]keyword = 2', line)
result.group(1) # 19:07:57.166
```

Comment: He wants the ip when the keyword is 2. So you have to filter your result.

Answer (score 1):

A possibility is to use `re` to transform your data into a list of dictionaries, making lookup with target keys a much cleaner process:

```
import re
data = [dict(zip(['val', 'keyword'], re.findall('^[\.\d:]+|(?<=keyword\s=\s)\d+', i))) for i in open('filename.txt')]
result = [i['val'] for i in data if int(i['keyword']) == 2]
```

Output:

```
['19:08:13.664', '19:14:43.061']
```